# Run macro at a particular time during the hour

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA-script that has some conditions from a time-perspective.

1. It needs to check the current time
2. If current time is earlier then 09:00:00 AM, it needs to run a macro at 09:00:00
3. When activated the macro need to run every 5 minutes
4. If current time is later then then 09:00:00 AM, it needs to run a at a x-fold of 5 minutes. For example 09:05:00 AM, 09:25:00 AM or 09:35:00 A

I have written the following code to address (1) and (2):

```
Sub Time()
Dim tm As Date
tm = TimeValue("09:00:00 AM")
If tm <= TimeValue(Now) Then
Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:00:00"), "Run_Macro"
Else
'Do something
End If
End Sub
```

For (3) the following code satisfies:

```
Sub Run_Macro_1()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:5:00"), "Run_Macro_2"
End Sub
```

However, (4) is the part where I am struggling with.

How do I make sure that the script "waits" until there is x-fold of 5 minutes on the clock? For example, if it currently 09:13:14, the script needs to wait until it is 09:15:00 to run.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think the [Application.Wait Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Wait) function is what you are looking for. It pauses a running macro until a specified time. Examples are on the link provided and seem pretty straight forward.

Absolute wait time:

```
Application.Wait "09:00:00"
```

And relative:

```
newHour = Hour(Now()) 
newMinute = Minute(Now()) + 5 
newSecond = Second(Now())
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond) 
Application.Wait waitTime
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as it still seems a plausible solution to me.